# How can I solve Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in this case

Tags: php

I get the error `Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading on line` at `return $array[];` inside the function.

I'm using PHP Version 7.0.1 on Windows 10.

I'm trying to get the output as follows:

```
<i>Error Line One...</i><br>
<i>Error Line Two...</i><br>
```

, in `json_encode`

`{"s":"Error Line One...<\/i>Error Line Two...<\/i>","success":false}`

I previously used a different approach, but switched to this yesterday.

How can I get this work?

```
$errorCount = 1;

$errors[] = '*Error Line One...';
$errors[] = '*Error Line Two...';

$errors['success'] = ($errorCount == 0 ? True : False);

$errors[] = ajax($errors);

function ajax($array) {
    $array = preg_replace('#\*(.+?)(?![^*])#','<i>$1</i><br>',$array);
    return $array[];
}

json_encode($errors);
```

Below is how it was done previously, then changed to the above to avoid the `.=` parts. This approach works. See [Fiddle](https://eval.in/553512).

```
$errorCount = 1;

$errors['s'] = '*Error Line One...';
$errors['s'] .= '*Error Line Two...';


$errors['s'] = ajax($errors);

function ajax($array) {
    $array = preg_replace('#\*(.+?)(?![^*])#','<i>$1</i>',$array);
    return $array['s'];
}
$errors['success'] = ($errorCount == 0 ? True : False);

echo json_encode($errors);
```

Comment: same index `s` are not allowed first and second `.=` not works for array

Comment: `return $array;` easy fix

Answer (score 1):

You are returning $array[] instead of $array,

Change this:

```
function ajax($array) {
    $array = preg_replace('#\*(.+?)(?![^*])#','<i>$1</i><br>',$array);
    return $array[];
}
```

into this:

```
function ajax($array) {
    return preg_replace('#\*(.+?)(?![^*])#','<i>$1</i><br>',$array);
}
```

edit:

This fixes it I guess:

```
<?php

$errorCount = 1;

$errors[] = '*Error Line One...';
$errors[] = '*Error Line Two...';
$errors = ajax($errors);
$errors['success'] = ($errorCount == 0 ? True : False);

function ajax($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
        $array[$key] = preg_replace('#\*(.+?)(?![^*])#','<i>$1</i><br>', $value);
    return $array;
}

echo json_encode($errors);

?>
```

Comment: I did this before. The output I'm looking to get is `{"s":"Error Line One...<\/i>Error Line Two...<\/i>","success":false}`. Doing what you suggested gives me something totally else.

Comment: Aha, didn't look at your code. I thought the only thing you wanted to fix was the error. I made an edit in my answer. This should work

Comment: Any chance this can be done without the foreach loop?

Comment: Perhaps with some array_map function.. But this doesn't make your code more readable.. It works? BTW, perhaps it's a better idea to format the html on the json_decode part.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. Since I'm the only guy who'll be reading this code.