# Fatal error : Cannot use [] for reading

Tags: php, sql

I used `implode` in my `request SQL`, for a `checkBox` for multiple choice.

```
if ($this->_count == 0) {
    $this->_sqlWhere.="`piecearticles`.`ID_Article`=`article`.`ID_Article` AND `piecearticles`.`Designiation`=`article`.`Designiation` AND `article`.`ID_LRU`=`lru`.`ID_LRU` AND lru.LRU IN (" . implode(",", $this->_lru[]) . ")"; 
    $this->_count++;
}
```

When I run it return an error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading
```

Is't the `implode` a cause to this error or in my request ?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `[]`? You only use it to push a value on an array, not to read from it.

Comment: Do you understand what syntax `$this->_lru[]` means?

Comment: `$this->_lru['']` or ` $this->_lru`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I solve Fatal error: Cannot use \[\] for reading in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627143/how-can-i-solve-fatal-error-cannot-use-for-reading-in-this-case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is what the error says - you can't use `[]` when you're trying to read an array. You can do;

```
implode(",", $this->_lru)
```

Or

```
implode(",", array("a2", "b"))
```

You only use the square brackets when you want to write **into** an array.